# Chasles decoposition of helical displacement given with quaternions

Tags: quaternions, affine-geometry

let $q =\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ + $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$i

and consider the map $x \to qxq^{-1} + i + j$

why is it a helical displacement? the axis of rotation is $i$, but the translation is $i + j$, and i thought the translation must parallel to the axis of rotation.

and how could i find the Chasles decomposition of this transformation?

Comment: The translation by $j$ can be absorbed into the rotation (by rotating about a parallel axis through another point), but translation by multiples of $i$ don't have this fix available.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the $jk$-plane (i.e., orthogonal complement to our axis $\langle i\rangle$), rotation about by $\theta$ then translate by $j$ fixes the point  $\frac12j+\frac{\sin\theta}{2-2\cos\theta}k$.  So you can describe the map as "translate by $i$ and rotate by $\theta$ about the axis $\frac12j+\frac{\sin\theta}{2-2\cos\theta}k+\langle i\rangle$.